# mysql update related row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, foreign-key-relationship

I have a mysql database with two tables, `users` and `items`. I want to update a variable on a row from `items` (which I can do) with UPDATE and then update a variable on the related row in `users`.

I am confused on updating using the foreign key, is this possible in one query? How do I go about this?

EDIT

Currently I am doing this in php:

```
//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "UPDATE items SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE id='$_POST[id]'")
  or die("Unable to query");

// update user score
$score = mysqli_query($dbhandle, "UPDATE users u JOIN items i ON u.id = i.user_id SET u.score = u.score + i.likes")
    or die("Unable to update user score");
```

Every row in items has a foreign key 'user_id', I just want to update the score of the related user based on how many likes the newly updated item now has

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data, data layouts, and the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Join` on both the table and perform the `UPDATE` like (a sample below)

```
UPDATE users u 
    JOIN items i ON u.some_col = i.some_col
SET u.column1 = i.column1
```

Also, if you have a `foreign key` relationship defined between the tables then you can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` (You will have to define while creation of the table or perform `ALTER` and change the schema) which will cascade the update between Main and Derived table.

Comment: I tried this, but I am not having luck: UPDATE users u JOIN ideas i ON u.id = i.user_id SET u.score = u.score + i.likes

Comment: Strange! can you prepare a fiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/) with those 2 table involved in the update query.